# Calculating sum using parallel programming

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I want to add 1 to a number(0) for 10 billion times. I tried two approaches -

1. Use a single thread (main thread) to do the work.
2. Create two threads and do half of the addition in 1st thread and the other half in the second.

I was expecting the second approach to take less time than the first one but the result is
opposite of that. Following are the timings using multi-threaded approach and single thread
(main thread) respectively.

```
real    0m35.661s    
user    1m6.652s
sys 0m0.004s

real    0m25.162s
user    0m25.162s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Following is the source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static unsigned long long int sum1, sum2;
long long unsigned int l1 = 10000000000/2;
long long unsigned int l2 = 10000000000/2 + 1;  

void *thread1(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long long int i;
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
    for (i=0;i<l1; i++)
        sum1 += 1;

    pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

void *thread2(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long long int i;
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
#if 0
    /* In case of single thread, the following for loop is used */
    for (i=0;i<10000000000; i++)
        sum2 += 1;
#endif
    for (i=l2;i<10000000000; i++)
        sum2 += 1;

    pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    void *res1, *res2;
    void *(*tptr)(void *);

    printf("%llu, %llu\n", l1, l2);
    /* all pthread_* calls are disabled in single thread mode
     * only main thread used which calls -thread2- method */
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, &thread1, NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, &thread2, NULL);

    if(pthread_join(tid1, NULL))
            printf("Error joining with t1");
    if(pthread_join(tid2, NULL))
            printf("Error joining with t2");

/* Enable  for single thread mode */
#if 0
    tptr = thread2;
    tptr(NULL);
#endif
    printf("Main thread exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

One reason that I can think of is maybe scheduling-overhead of the threads is causing
more time in case multi-thread case. Is there some more explanation to this ?

===============
After trying the solution suggested in the accepted answer, I saw the
following readings in multi-thread case -

```
real    0m12.526s
user    0m23.375s
sys 0m0.004s
```

which is as expected, almost half of what I get with a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **false sharing**. `sum1` and `sum2` are stored in the same cache line, so stores to them are competing, which leads to serialization.

You can use `alignas` to force them to separate cache lines.

```
alignas(64) static unsigned long long int sum1, sum2;
```

This is however all artifact of not using optimizations. It makes no sense to store intermediate values of the sum in RAM, it should be in register and compiler would probably do this if you compiled with optimizations enabled. Then however, it would also eliminate entire loops, since effect of the repeated addition is predictable.